# Downloading a ZIP file with R is unsuccessful as I receive a corrupted file

Tags: r, download, zip

this is my first question over here so I hope it's posted correctly - please let me know if not.

I'm trying to download a ZIP file with R which is around 35 MB from the link below. Manual download works fine, but using R download doesn't work as I receive a 15 KB file which is obviously some kind of error. I've seen various thread like this but no solution has worked for me.

```
url = "https://www.kaggle.com/hugomathien/soccer/downloads/soccer.zip"

download.file(url, dest="./soccer.zip", mode="wb")

Content type 'text/html; charset=utf-8' length 15663 bytes (15 KB)
downloaded 15 KB
```

Comment: It requires an active login session. Try using `httr` and `POST()` credentials to kaggle's login form page. That should setup the proper local cookies within the curl handle pool to enable using something like `GET(url, write_disk('./soccer.zip'))`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was so frustrated with it. If it's not too much to ask, can somebody help providing me a code with POST and GET? I tried to make them work and google them but without success, I didn't really understand the difference between them